# RFC 4122 UUID on Android?

Tags: android, uuid

Is there a way to generate RFC 4122 version 1 UUIDs on Android? UUID version 1 means timestamp-based UUIDs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you checked [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html)

```
public static String deviceUDID(Context ctx) {
 final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

 final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
 tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
 tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
 androidId = "" +android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

 UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
 String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
 Log.d("Device Id", deviceId);
 return deviceId;
}
```

You can also refer [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/generate-random-uuid-and-store-it) and [this](http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/) links too.

Comment: will this work on tablets (I'm not sure if TelephonyManager is available there)

Comment: Where is the timestamp in this generation?

Comment: @Navigateur : Check here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#timestamp()

Comment: @GirishNair But that is how to get the time stamp from a version 1 (timestamp based) UUID. You are not using timestamp in generating the UUID, so it is not a version 1 (or timestamp based) UUID in the first place. This is the wrong answer. The question is asking for a version 1 timestamp based UUID. Your code will give the same UUID every time, which breaks the uniqueness per time stamp that is required to be a version 1 (timestamp based) UUID, and is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Navigateur: Then please post a correct answer and stop waisting my time. The person who had asked the question seemed to be satisfied with the answer that I gave. or go and ask a separate question and answer it yourself if it satisfies you. Why can you just add a time stamp at the end of the UUID. I gave a developer reference and the people asking questions in stackoverflow are not spoon fed with answers exact to their needs

Comment: This answer is extremely wrong and definitely should not be the accepted one. This is neither RFC 4122 nor type 1 (time-based). *DO NOT* use this in production.

Comment: @fpg1503 : Then please post the correct answer and enlighten us also ask the user to accept your answer

Comment: @GirishNair: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844709) shows the right way to do it

Comment: @fpg1503 : Good Andreas Jung Please update your accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [JUG library](http://www.makeinjava.com/time-based-uuid-generator-java-jug-example/)?

In their example, they show how to generate a time-based UUID like the code below:

```
NoArgGenerator timeBasedGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(); 
UUID firstUUID = timeBasedGenerator.generate();
```

Or you can generate it from device network interface (if your Android version allows hardware information access):

```
timeBasedGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(EthernetAddress.fromInterface());
UUID customUUID = timeBasedGenerator.generate();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/marccarre/cassandra-utils

It works for me.
U need just one class: cassandra-utils/src/main/java/com/carmatech/cassandra/TimeUUID.java
And one dependency in your build.gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eaio.uuid/uuid
**compile group: 'com.eaio.uuid', name: 'uuid', version: '3.2'**
```

**WARNING** Random will be used instead of MAC-address, but you can change it.

```
import com.eaio.uuid.UUIDGen;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public final class TimeUUID {
private TimeUUID() {
    // Pure utility class, do NOT instantiate.
}

private static final long NUM_100NS_INTERVALS_SINCE_UUID_EPOCH = 0x01b21dd213814000L;
private static long lastTimestamp = Long.MIN_VALUE;

/**
 * WARNING: Use only for testing purposes, as it may lead to duplicate UUIDs. Re-initialize the value of the last timestamp seen.
 */
public static synchronized void reset() {
    lastTimestamp = Long.MIN_VALUE;
}

/**
 * Generate a new, unique UUID based on current timestamp.
 */
public static UUID createUUID() {
    return createUUID(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

/**
 * Generate a new, unique UUID based on the provided date-time.
 *
 * @param dateTime date-time used for the "time" component of the UUID.
 */
public static UUID createUUID(final DateTime dateTime) {
    return createUUID(dateTime.getMillis());
}

/**
 * Generate a new, unique UUID based on the provided date.
 *
 * @param javaDate date used for the "time" component of the UUID.
 */
public static UUID createUUID(final Date javaDate) {
    return createUUID(javaDate.getTime());
}

/**
 * Generate a new, unique UUID based on the provided timestamp.
 *
 * @param timestamp timestamp used for the "time" component of the UUID.
 */
public static UUID createUUID(final long timestamp) {
    final long timestampIn100Ns = to100Ns(timestamp);
    final long uniqueTimestampIn100Ns = makeUnique(timestampIn100Ns);
    return new UUID(toUUIDTime(uniqueTimestampIn100Ns), UUIDGen.getClockSeqAndNode());
}

private static long to100Ns(final long timestampInMs) {
    return (timestampInMs * 10000) + NUM_100NS_INTERVALS_SINCE_UUID_EPOCH;
}

private static synchronized long makeUnique(final long timestamp) {
    if (timestamp > lastTimestamp) {
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        return timestamp;
    } else {
        return ++lastTimestamp;
    }
}

private static long toUUIDTime(final long timestampIn100Ns) {
    // Example:
    // Lowest 16 bits and version 1: 0123 4567 89AB CDEF -> 89AB CDEF 0000 0000 -> 89AB CDEF 0000 1000
    // Middle 32 bits: 0123 4567 89AB CDEF -> 0000 4567 0000 0000 -> 0000 0000 4567 0000 -> 89AB CDEF 4567 1000
    // Highest 16 bits: 0123 4567 89AB CDEF -> 0123 0000 0000 0000 -> 0000 0000 0000 0123 -> 89AB CDEF 4567 1123

    long uuidTime = (timestampIn100Ns << 32) | 0x0000000000001000L;
    uuidTime |= (timestampIn100Ns & 0x0000FFFF00000000L) >>> 16;
    uuidTime |= (timestampIn100Ns & 0xFFFF000000000000L) >>> 48;
    return uuidTime;
}

/**
 * WARNING: returned UUID is not unique. Get the UUID corresponding to the provided date-time and the clock sequence, which depends on the IP and MAC
 * addresses of the current machine, and a random component per process/JVM.
 *
 * @param dateTime date-time used for the "time" component of the UUID.
 */
public static UUID toUUID(final DateTime dateTime) {
    return toUUID(dateTime.getMillis());
}

/**
 * WARNING: returned UUID is not unique. Get the UUID corresponding to the provided date and the clock sequence, which depends on the IP and MAC addresses
 * of the current machine, and a random component per process/JVM.
 *
 * @param javaDate date used for the "time" component of the UUID.
 */
public static UUID toUUID(final Date javaDate) {
    return toUUID(javaDate.getTime());
}

/**
 * WARNING: returned UUID is not unique. Get the UUID corresponding to the provided timestamp and the clock sequence, which depends on the IP and MAC
 * addresses of the current machine, and a random component per process/JVM.
 *
 * @param timestamp timestamp used for the "time" component of the UUID.
 */
public static UUID toUUID(final long timestamp) {
    final long timestampIn100Ns = to100Ns(timestamp);
    return new UUID(toUUIDTime(timestampIn100Ns), UUIDGen.getClockSeqAndNode());
}

/**
 * Extract the "time" component of the provided UUID.
 *
 * @param uuid UUID to extract timestamp from.
 * @return Timestamp in milliseconds.
 */
public static long toMillis(final UUID uuid) {
    return from100Ns(uuid.timestamp());
}

private static long from100Ns(long timestampIn100Ns) {
    return (timestampIn100Ns - NUM_100NS_INTERVALS_SINCE_UUID_EPOCH) / 10000;
}
```

}